# How to make sure that Sitecore item rollback was correct?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I am working on a Continuous Integration project where I need to install update packages in Sitecore instances and roll back the update package if something goes wrong. I am creating the update and rollback update package using Sitecore Courier. I just want to know if there is any mechanism to confirm that my rollback worked correctly i.e. the Sitecore instance has been restored to its previous state.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have something out of the box to check if something goes wrong.

I suggest you to create few unit tests using Sitecore FakeDb and check if old 
templates still exist, if content is the same,etc

Informations about FakeDb you can find at: https://github.com/sergeyshushlyapin/Sitecore.FakeDb/wiki